# Define class constant by another class constant in php

Tags: php

How do I define a class constant based on another constant in the same class?

```
class A{
    const BASE_URL = 'http://example.org'
    const API_URL = BASE_URL . '/api';  // < error
}
```

Comment: You could try `Self::BASE_URL` I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can only initialize class constants with constant values. You pass
> a statement which has to be evaluated at runtime, while the class
> constants are defined at compile time which comes earlier.

So. this is not possible.
[Check this incorrect bug report.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42355)

**Update:**

It's possible since `php-5.6`:

```
class A {
    const BASE_URL = 'http://example.org';
    const API_URL = self::BASE_URL . '/api';
}

echo echo A::API_URL; // http://example.org/api
```

[Check the doc to learn more about it.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)